# How to call pywin32 via RPyC from the Linux box

Tags: python, linux, windows, rpyc

**Intro:**

I have a Linux box with Python 2.7 and RPyC on it. Additionally I have a Windows (Server 2008) box installed with the same Python version, RPyC and pywin32. Windows box runs RPyC classic_server and Linux box is used to run RPyC client. Generally, I'm building infra to manage Active Directory (AD) server in remote from the Linux box. For AD management will be used "pyad" module installed on Windows machine.

**Question:**

Generally, all this bundle works as promised.

```
In [3]: conn = rpyc.classic.connect("10.103.224.44")
In [4]: conn.modules.os.getcwd()
Out[4]: 'C:\\ldap-automation-project\\scripts'
```

But it fails when I try to call remote "pywin32" or "pyad" (pywin32 is a dependency).

```
In [7]: conn.modules.pywin32
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-31ec7f3bb520> in <module>()
----> 1 conn.modules.pywin32

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpyc/core/service.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
    119         return self.__cache[name]
    120     def __getattr__(self, name):
--> 121         return self[name]
    122 
    123 class SlaveService(Service):

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpyc/core/service.pyc in __getitem__(self, name)
    116             name = ".".join(name)
    117         if name not in self.__cache:
--> 118             self.__cache[name] = self.__getmodule(name)
    119         return self.__cache[name]
    120     def __getattr__(self, name):

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpyc/core/netref.pyc in __call__(_self, *args, **kwargs)
    194         def __call__(_self, *args, **kwargs):
    195             kwargs = tuple(kwargs.items())
--> 196             return syncreq(_self, consts.HANDLE_CALL, args, kwargs)
    197         __call__.__doc__ = doc
    198         return __call__

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpyc/core/netref.pyc in syncreq(proxy, handler, *args)
     69         raise ReferenceError('weakly-referenced object no longer exists')
     70     oid = object.__getattribute__(proxy, "____oid__")
---> 71     return conn.sync_request(handler, oid, *args)
     72 
     73 def asyncreq(proxy, handler, *args):

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpyc/core/protocol.pyc in sync_request(self, handler, *args)
    439         isexc, obj = self._sync_replies.pop(seq)
    440         if isexc:
--> 441             raise obj
    442         else:
    443             return obj

ImportError: No module named pywin32

========= Remote Traceback (1) =========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 305, in _dispatch_request
    res = self._HANDLERS[handler](self, *args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 535, in _handle_call
    return self._local_objects[oid](*args, **dict(kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\service.py", line 163, in exposed_getmodule
    return __import__(name, None, None, "*")
ImportError: No module named pywin32
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `win32api`, etc, are top-level imports. The project name is PyWin32.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @eryksun 
But it still doesn't work.
I get:
ImportError: No module named win32api

In comparison to some basic standard module like OS:
In [11]: conn.modules.os
Out[11]: <module 'os' from 'C:\Python27\lib\os.pyc'>

Comment: Can you import win32api in an interactive logon?

Comment: Yes, I can. It works like a charm when I import it from the local iPython but fails remotely.

Comment: In the local IPython case, what is `win32api.__file__`? In the remote case, is this directory in `sys.path`?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the import error for `win32api`.